# Cube with louvre planes in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this code which produces the diagram below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,positioning,arrows,calc,matrix,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{colone}{RGB}{209,220,204}
\definecolor{coltwo}{RGB}{204,222,210}
\definecolor{colthree}{RGB}{207,233,232}
\definecolor{colfour}{RGB}{248,243,214}
\definecolor{colfive}{RGB}{245,238,197}
\definecolor{colsix}{RGB}{243,235,179}
\definecolor{colseven}{RGB}{241,231,163}
\definecolor{colortop}{RGB}{184,223,155}
\definecolor{colorside}{RGB}{0,209,54}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,font=\scriptsize},on grid]
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=-0.5},yslant=-0.5]
  \shade[right color=colorside!30, left color=colorside!50] (-1,0) rectangle +(4,3);
  \node  at (-0.5,2.25) {};
  \node at (0.5,2.75) {$Sex$};
  \node at (1.5,2.75) {$Age$};
  \node at (2.5,2.75) {$Area$};
  \node at (-0.5,1.25) {$User_3$};
  \node at (-0.5,0.75) {$...$};
  \node at (0.5,0.75) {$...$};
  \node at (2.5,0.75) {$...$};
  \node at (0.5,1.25) {$*$};
  \node at (1.5,1.25) {$4$};
   \node at (2.5,1.25) {$0$};
   \node at (-0.5,0.25) {$User_n$};
   \node at (1.5,0.75) {$...$};
   \node at (-0.5,2.25) {$user_1$};
   \node at (0.5,2.25) {$0$};
   \node at (1.5,2.25) {$*$};
   \node at (2.5,2.25) {$1$};
    \node at (-0.5,1.75) {$User_2$};
    \node at (0.5,1.75) {$1$};
    \node at (1.5,1.75) {$3$};
    \node at (2.5,1.75) {$0$};
    \node at (0.5,0.25) {$2$};
    \node at (1.5,0.25) {$*$};
    \node at (2.5,0.25) {$9$};
  \draw (-1,0) grid[ystep=0.5] (3,3);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=0.5},yslant=0.5]
  \shade[right color=colorside!70,left color=colorside!10] (3,-3) rectangle +(5,3);
  \node at (3.5,-0.25) {};
  \node at (3.5,-0.75) {$user_1$};
  \node at (3.5,-1.25) {$user_2$};
  \node at (3.5,-1.75){$user_3$};
  \node at (3.5,-2.25) {$...$};
  \node at (3.5,-2.75) {$user_n$};
  \node at (4.5,-0.25) {$item_1$};
  \node at (4.5,-1.25) {$3$};
  \node at (4.5,-0.75) {$*$};
  \node at (4.5,-1.75) {$*$};
  \node at (4.5,-2.25) {$...$};
  \node at (4.5,-2.75) {$*$};
  \node at (5.5,-0.25) {$item_2$};
  \node at (5.5,-0.75) {$2$};
  \node at (5.5,-1.75) {$3$};
  \node at (5.5,-1.25) {$4$};
   \node at (5.5,-2.75) {$5$};
  \node at (5.5,-2.25) {$...$};
  \node at (6.5,-0.25) {$...$};
  \node at (6.5,-1.25) {$...$};
  \node at (6.5,-2.25) {$...$};
  \node at (6.5,-0.75) {$...$};
  \node at (6.5,-1.75) {$...$};
  \node at (6.5,-2.75) {$...$};
  \node at (7.5,-0.25) {$item_n$};
  \node at (7.5,-0.75) {$3$};
  \node at (7.5,-1.25) {$5$};
  \node at (7.5,-1.75) {$4$};
  \node at (7.5,-2.25) {$...$};
  \node at (7.5,-2.75) {$*$};





  \draw (3,-3) grid[ystep=0.5] (8,0);
 \end{scope}
\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={
    yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-0.75
  ]
  \shade[bottom color=colortop!10, top color=colortop!80] (8,4) rectangle +(-5,-4);
\draw (3.0,0.0) grid[ystep=0.5] (8,4);
 \node at (3.5,3.75) {};
 \node at (3.5,3.25) {$Legal$};
 \node at (3.5,2.75) {$Fin.$};
 \node at (3.5,2.25) {$Med.$};
 \node at (3.5,1.75) {$Home$};
 \node at (3.5,1.25) {$Road$};
 \node at (3.5,0.75) {$Travel$};
  \node at (3.5,0.25) {$Din.$};
 \node at (4.5,3.75) {$item_1$};
  \node at (4.5,3.25) {$1$};
 \node at (4.5,2.75) {$0$};
 \node at (4.5,2.25) {$0$};
 \node at (4.5,1.75) {$1$};
 \node at (4.5,1.25) {$1$};
 \node at (4.5,0.75) {$0$};
 \node at (4.5,0.25) {$1$};
\node at (5.5,3.75) {$item_2$};
  \node at (5.5,3.25) {$1$};
  \node at (5.5,2.75) {$0$};
  \node at (5.5,2.25) {$0$};
  \node at (5.5,1.75) {$1$};
  \node at (5.5,1.25) {$0$};
  \node at (5.5,0.75) {$1$};
  \node at (5.5,0.25) {$1$};
 \node at (6.5,3.75) {$...$};
\node at (6.5,3.25) {$...$};
\node at (6.5,2.75) {$...$};
\node at (6.5,2.25) {$...$};
\node at (6.5,1.75) {$...$};
\node at (6.5,1.25) {$...$};
\node at (6.5,0.75) {$...$};
\node at (6.5,0.25) {$...$};
\node at (7.5,3.75) {$item_n$};
\node at (7.5,3.25) {$0$};
\node at (7.5,2.75) {$1$};
\node at (7.5,2.25) {$1$};
\node at (7.5,1.75) {$0$};
\node at (7.5,1.25) {$0$};
\node at (7.5,0.75) {$1$};
\node at (7.5,0.25) {$0$};


\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{User-Item Combined Matrix}
\label{fig:com}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Louvred Cube]

I'd like to do the following:

1. Open the right hand side plane at an angle to display data like the left hand side one
2. Open the bottom plane in the same way as the top one.
3. If possible, use different colours for each plane.

Comment: I don't really understand (1) or (2). For (1), it seems the data is already displayed as that panel is already shown. Is the problem the angle? Or are you talking about a plane not shown in the current diagram at all? Depending on the answer to that question, how exactly should (2) be shown? Should it stick out in front of the vertical plane to which it is attached rather than being angled behind it?

Comment: The planes that are already shown are the left, the top and the centre. I want to show the right and the bottom planes.

Comment: It would be nice if you made the example compilable.

Comment: I have edited the code to make it compilable. I want the right and bottom planes to open out so I can add both user (right) and item (bottom) attributes. The centre plane indicates the intersection between user and item data. In short, I can describe a user by the items he has used and I can also describe an item by the users who have used it.